# RegExp works as string but not in an object Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, object

I am trying to simplify my code by storing all my regexes in an object and just calling them in as a parameter for one function. The issue is, for some reason, it does not work as such. Could someone tell me what I am missing here?

Here is the working code:

```
function alphaNumericVal(input) {
var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$");
return regex.test(input);
}

var testString = "FGDFGfg%$#d4334";

document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = alphaNumericVal(testString);
```

This is what I am trying to do instead:

```
var expr = {
  alphaNumeric:"^[a-zA-Z\d]+$"
};

function genericFunc(input, regExp) {
  var regex = new RegExp(regExp);
  return regex.test(input); 
}

var testString = "FGDFGfg%$#d4334";

document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = genericFunc(testString, expr.alpaNumeric);
```

The working code returns false as expected since "testString" is not alpha numeric. The bottom code always returns true.

Comment: Have you tried goi g back to 0-9 instead of \d? I suspect that's screwing it up. To use \d you'd need \\d

Comment: `\d` should be `\\d`. ``\`` is the escape character in string literals. If you do `console.log(expr. alphaNumeric)`, you will see. Better yet, use an regular expression literal: `/^[a-zA-Z\d]+$/`. No need for `RegEx`. You only need  `RegExp` when you build the expression dynamically.

Comment: You have a typo, `alphaNumeric:"^[a-zA-Z\d]+$"` and your parameter is `expr.alpaNumeric` without `h`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I changed that back and forth a few times and still running into the same issue. Even when I use "\\d".

Comment: @itsgoingdown - Thanks! Ah I was banging my head over this one. That solved it.

Comment: Could you close this question if it's solved?